# Accessing the element of a view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dom, backbone.js

I've dipped my toes in Backbone.js and it's been a real treat so far. Very simple, yet extremely powerful. Awesome library!

**I'm having one problem though:** I can't seem a way to access the linked element(the `el` property) of my views.

My example below alerts `undefined`. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8B2U/) to see it in action.

```
$(function() {
    // Init when DOM is Ready
    App.init();
});

var App = {
    init: function() {
        new App.MyView();
    }
}

App.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#some-id',
    initialize: function() {
        App.MyController.doSomething();
    }
});

App.MyController = {
    doSomething: function() {
        alert('MyView.el: ' + App.MyView.el); // Outputs 'MyView.el: undefined'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 problems:

1. You have defined `el` as a selector, so it must be in the DOM
2. You tried to alert the constructor's `el` property instead of the instance `el` property.

Fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/X8B2U/2/

```html
<div id="some-id"></div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    // Init when DOM is Ready
    App.init();
});

var App = {
    init: function() {
       new App.MyView();

    }
}

App.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#some-id',
    initialize: function() {
        App.MyController.doSomething(this);
    }
});

App.MyController = {
    doSomething: function( myView ) {
        console.log( myView );
        alert('MyView.el: ' + myView.el);
    }
}
```

Comment: I never knew you could do `el: 'some-id'` - I always thought it had to be `el: $('some-id')` (if you change the fiddle you do see the difference in the alert. Any reason?

Comment: @Nupul, el: `$('some-id')` finds the element before the view is initialized... so you don't wanna do it because it ties the class declaration to DOMReady. And backbone doesn't expect a jQuery object anyway.

Comment: OMG! Wasn't aware of it! NO EXAMPLE I've ever seen showed the `el` binding properly anyways!!

Comment: @Nupul, basically you either leave the `el` `undefined`, in which case an element is created or you pass a css selector which will call jQuery on it when you intialize the view, and then retrieve the underlying DOM element from the jQuery object and set that as `el`. In case where element is created, it is created according to tagName, id and such properties. The element created this way also needs to be manually inserted into the DOM. This is documented [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el)

Comment: You mean if BB views are declared with `el: 'class/id-selector'` you can declare them outside the DOMReady (i.e., `$(document).ready(...)` and just use their declarations within it, correct?

Comment: @Nupul, yes that way the class declarations may be anywhere while only the  initialization code needs to be done in DOMReady because that's the point of time when the elements are looked for when using css selectors.

Comment: Hmmm...it seems the BB docs has gotten updated...I've never seen that el binding example before and that's always been a troublesome aspect for me! Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Thanks @Esailija! It makes sense, but i thought i was creating a new instance in the init function of App by typing: `new App.MyView();`. Do I need to assign it to a seperate global variable for that to work?

Comment: @Ahrengot, that does create a new instance - except the instance reference isn't saved anywhere. `var myInstance = new App.MyView();` and the instance could be accessed from `myInstance` afterwards. That's just an example.

Comment: Man you're fast. :) Still getting used to stackoverflow's comments. Was trying to format the code but indenting by 4 spaces didn't work.  Anyway, thanks for the help. This clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

The el property should be a jquery element referencing an existing DOM element.

```
el : $('#some-id')
```